# Bat file to create a Windows 7 shortcut.lnk on my desktop

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, batch-file, shortcut-file, lnk

How can I create a bat or vbs file to create a Windows 7 compatible desktop shortcut?

I need the bat or vbs file to create the desktop shortcut using the following target and start-in locations (below). I basically created a desktop app that uses Google Chrome Portable to render my webapp as if it is Windows native and the shortcut will launch Chrome so it is very lightweight and looks like a genuine Windows application kinda like what Prism used to do. I've tried manually creating the shortcut.lnk but when my user installs my app it wont extract my shortcut.lnk via this path C:\Users\Public\Desktop so thats why I am now trying to create a bat or vbs file I can run on install. Thanks for your help.

Target:

C:\MyProgram\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\MyProgram\Data\profile" --app=http://my-web-site-url.com/

Start in:

C:\MyProgram\App\Chrome-bin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your installer should be able to do this ... here is how in VBS:

```
Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\XXXX.LNK")

lnk.targetpath = "C:\MyProgram\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe"
lnk.arguments = "--user-data-dir=""C:\MyProgram\Data\profile"" --app=http://my-web-site-url.com/"
lnk.description = "Bla bla"
lnk.workingdirectory = "C:\MyProgram\App\Chrome-bin" 
lnk.save
```

Comment: Dude, that is awesome, it worked! How do I specify a icon using your script. Thank you so very much

Comment: lnk.IconLocation ref; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: One last question, your awesome. Could Do some such as this? I tried like this and get a error lnk.IconLocation ref = "%SystemDrive%\MyProgram\Data\profile\Default\Web Applications\my-web-site-url.com\http_80\logo.ico"

Comment: To expand the environment vars use ExpandEnvironmentStrings: `lnk.IconLocation = wsc.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%\MyProgram\Data\profile\Default\Web Applications\my-web-site-url.com\http_80\logo.ico")`

Comment: worked like a charm. You have been such a great help. Thank you so much again, I guess we can now say my question is officially resolved. TY. Now I just need to figure out how to rep you for the help

Comment: Your welcome, just tick the tick next to the answer if you would like to accept it.

Comment: Ah, ok. I just click the check. Any idea how I can convert this vbs to a bat now?

Comment: You should be able to just run the vbs file or run `cscript xxx.vbs` from a bat

Comment: cscript xxx.vbs from a bat did it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi bud, do you know how to set the shortcut.lnk to be Maximized by default within the vbs script? I try several combinations and failed. lnk.run = wsc.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("Maximized") and also tried lnk.run = "Maximized"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **INTERNAL** command `MKLINK` to make a **SYMBOLIC** link (ie: It acts just like the file it's linked to).

You need to have an elevated command prompt, or have the Administrator account activated (with a password set, as `RUNAS` will not accept a blank password).

From an elevated command prompt:

`mklnk.bat`

```
@echo off
mklink %~n1.lnk %~dpnx1
```

With an active Administrator account:

`mklnk.bat`

```
@echo off
runas /user:administrator "cmd /c mklink %~dpn1.lnk %~dpnx1"
```

Because `mklink` is an **internal** command, you can't use `RUNAS` to directly access it, but you can run `CMD.EXE` as the Administrator, and then call `mklink` from there.

---

Both of the above batch files will accept the same options and create the same files in the same place. So if you call the batch file `mklnk.bat` :

```
c:>mklnk welcome.msg
symbolic link created for welcome.lnk <<===>> welcome.msg
```

Another `CMD.EXE` window will flash on the screen, but that is normal.

Comment: The above will not put the link on the desktop, but rather in the same directory as the indicated file. In the example I gave above, it's in the current directory.